# How do I find a stream function given a volumetric flow rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, potential-flow

How do I find a [stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) given a volumetric flow rate?

The flow only occurs in one direction, between 2 plates,  and I have no knowledge of velocity.

I know that volumetric flow rate = change in stream function between two points but I have no idea how to apply this.

Comment: It isn't possible to determine the stream function, given only the volumetric flow rate.  Were you given any other information, such as what the total area perpendicular to the flow is?  Or did you perhaps misread the problem, and it's actually the volumetric flux that's given, instead of the volumetric flow rate?

Comment: Is the fluid flow pressure-driven laminar flow, or is it generated by moving one of the plates?

Comment: it's a pressure driven flow ie like a river flowing wiith the plates as its banks and I know the distaance between the two plates. what's the difference between flux and flow rate? i am given a quantity in units of vol/time

Comment: I think what i wrote is the best you can do. You only know stream function in the middle of the river and at the banks. Unless is pure sheer flow. / Flow rate assumes the depth into the page is a length of 1 and gives volumetric flow rate that way, so the units are volume per time, like m^3/sec. Flux is the volumetric flow rate per unit depth so units are m^2/sec. Other than units they are equal. Actual real flow rate (also m^3/sec) would require knowing how deep the plates or river are. Technically stream func can be defined on either. I didnt assume anything because different Q’a poss in it

Answer (score 0):

If it is pure shear flow, with the top plate moving with velocity V and the lower plate stationary, the stream function is given by $$\psi=Q\left(\frac{y}{h}\right)^2$$where Q is the total volumetric flow rate, equal to Vh/2, h is the distance between the plates, and y is the distance measured upward from the bottom plate.

Comment: Im pretty sure that equation assumes you are only moving the plates, with no other source of flow. I think he has stationary plates and some flow.

Comment: @Al Brown That may very well be.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two stationary plates h apart and know Q. You know that the fluid is not flowing at the boundary of the plates (right up against the plates, this is called the no-slip boundary condition), so at y= 0 and y= h, the velocity is zero.

You also know that the flow is symmetrical about the height y= h/2 because the plates are not moving, and the max velocity and max stream function is at y= h/2. The region from y= 0 to y= h/2 has Q/2 flowing through it (as does the region from y= h/2 to y= h) due to the symmetry.

The difference between the stream function at y= 0 and y= h/2 is equal to the flow through that region, which is Q/2, because Q/2 also flows through the other symmetrical region. We also know stream function at y= 0 is zero. These two facts mean the stream function is Q/2 at y= h/2, which is the max value of the stream function. It goes from 0 at y=0 to Q/2 at y=h/2 back to 0 at y=h. That’s all we know for sure.

If it is pure sheer, then it is linear. Stream = yQ/h from y= 0 to h/2 and Stream = Q - yQ/h from y= h/2 to h.